# SSKeychain - NSArray to NSString/NSMutableString extra characters

Tags: ios, objective-c, sskeychain

I am trying to use `SSKeychain` in my application to store a user's credentials. I can successfully save the credentails. However, when I try to retrieve the credentials, they are outputted as an NSArray. I want one specific value so I am using `valueForKey:NSString` which gives me `( acct )`

Here is the code I am using

```
NSArray *accounts = [SSKeychain accountsForService:@"testApp"];
NSString *account = [accounts valueForKey:@"acct"];
NSLog(@"%@", account);
```

I would like for the output to be `acct` not `(acct)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`accountsForService:` returns an array of dictionaries, not an array of strings. See the docs: http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/SSKeychain/1.2.2/Classes/SSKeychain.html#//api/name/accountsForService:

You can find the keys you should use to retrieve info from the dictionaries in SSKeyChain.h

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 NSArray *accounts = [SSKeychain accountsForService:@"testApp"];
 NSString *account = [[accounts valueForKey:@"acct"] objectAtIndex:0];

 NSLog(@"%@", account);
```